# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument opening Jupyter Notebook with Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, jupyter-notebook

When I try to start Jupyter notebook (installed with Anaconda3) via Windows Command Prompt it gives me the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because jupyter is missing the desired [IPython kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html) for use with Python 3. Just install the IPython kernel via the below command in cmd and relaunch jupyter, now it should be working:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

You can read more on jupyter and kernels [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-kernel.html).